# PM2 + Winston Log Management

Tags: node.js, pm2, winston

I want to have log files on a daily basis. I dont want both of them to create separate log files. I just want a single log file on a daily 
basis.

example: application-YYYY-MM-DD:HH:MM.log (Log Rotation)

How can I achieve this ?
Also, PM2 Log Rotate doesn't support timestamps for logging. So, How can I merge both features?

I Attached ecosystem.config.js as well as logger.js

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'API',
    script: 'app.js',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    output: `./logs/starter-logs.log`,
    error: `./logs/starter-errors.log`,
    log: './logs/combined.outerr.log',
    log_date_format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss:SS Z',
    append_env_to_name: true,
    // For merging cluster mode logs
    merge_logs: true,
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
      PORT: 3002,
      MONGODB_URI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      PORT: 3004,
    }
  }]
```

logger.js

```
const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    format.splat(),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: `${logFileName}-error.log`, level: 'error' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: `${logFileName}-combined.log` }),
    new transports.Console(),
  ]
});
```

Need a Single Log file, Instead of PM2 creating logs as well as Winston creating log files.

Also, I need File Transport as well as Console Transport. Please check the above code.